# How to implement role based authorization in Node.js using token based authentication?

Tags: node.js, rest, express, passport.js

How can I implement multiple authentications in nodejs for a education firm, having three role- student, parent, and admin using REST API approach i.e token based authentication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**0. Concept**

A JWT token (https://jwt.io/), contains a `payload`, within this payload you can specify a custom `role` object. Within the role object you can set boolean values to determine if the role is student, parent or admin.

*Example Payload*

```
{
  ...
  "role": {
     student: true,
     parent: false,
     admin: false,
  }
}
```

When you go to generate your token for a specific user, attach the payload details to the token. (Ofcourse you would adjust the payload details depending on whether you want the user to be a student, parent or admin).

Whenever a user makes a request in the future using their token, you can make a callback to check their token and look at the `payload.role` object to see what role the user has and then make a decision as to whether they are authorized to perform a specific action or not.

**1. Generating the token**

See https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken for more information on generating a token.

```
   const payload = {
     userid: 123,
     role: {
       student: false,
       parent: false,
       admin: true,
     },
   };

   const signOptions = {
     issuer: this.config.jwt.issuer,
     subject: payload.userid,
     audience: this.config.jwt.audience,
     expiresIn: "730d",
     algorithm: "RS256",
   };

   const token = jwt.sign(payload, this.config.jwt.privateKey.replace(/\\n/g, "\n"), signOptions);
```

**2. Middleware To Check Role**

You should already have something like this if youre are using passport with JWT authentication.

```
const authGuard = PassportMiddleware.authenticate("jwt", { session: false });

router.get("/admin", authGuard, controller.index);
```

We need a new middleware to handle the checking of roles. We will call this middleware `adminGuard`. After authenticating using the `authGuard` middleware the `req` object will contain a user (which is the jwt payload). Now that we have the user information we can check what role they have.

```
const adminGuard = (req, res, next) =>  {
     if(req.user && !req.user.role.admin) {
       next(new Error('You are not an admin'));
     } else {
       next();
     }
}

router.get("/admin", authGuard, adminGuard, controller.index);
```

You can create a new middleware guard for each role.

Comment: I understood the concept but could not understand the syntax to perform this. How to attach payload at the time of generating the token. And  what will be the syntax of checking role when verifying the token using token.verify() method.

Comment: Thanks, Kay. This is much more than I expected. I am sure this will work. I already had similar middleware checking the role. Now the syntax is pretty much clear to me. Thank you so much. I'll post any further query.